# .replace in AngularJs 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

In AngularJS I could do:

```html
<img ng-src="https://someimageurl/{{ foo.replace('bar','') }}" />
```

How can I achieve the same result in DOM with AngularJS 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<img ng-src="https://someimageurl/{{ foo.replace('bar','') }} />
```

is not an *angular replace method*, is just the *javascript replace method* being called inside angular interpolation.

In angular2, you can do the same by doing:

```
<img [src]="'https://someimageurl/' + foo.replace('bar','')"/>
```

You can find more information about Template Syntax in [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<img [src]="'https://someimageurl/' + foo.replace('bar','')" />
```

Comment: Works quite nicely, thanks. Doesn't feel very _Angular_ though. Before I accept the answer, is there a "recommended" way to do angular's deprecated .replace?

Comment: @JavaNoob No, there is no .replace method in angular. You need to do like JavaScript replace in the markup or in the Angular 2 Component.